# How can I refactor for handling multiple proto generated service clients by eliminating double await and the DRY code?

Tags: design-patterns, comparative-review, typescript, protocol-buffers

I'm having doubts about which is the best strategy to manage the many service clients in this web app.

**"Best" in terms of a good compromise between user's device RAM and Javascript execution speed (main thread ops).**

This is what I'm doing right now, this is the main file:

- main.ts:

```
import type { PlayerServiceClient } from './player.client';
import type { TeamServiceClient } from './team.client';
import type { RefereeServiceClient } from './referee.client';
import type { FriendServiceClient } from './friend.client';
import type { PrizeServiceClient } from './prize.client';
import type { WinnerServiceClient } from './winner.client';
import type { CalendarServiceClient } from './calendar.client';

let playerService: PlayerServiceClient;
export const player = async (): Promise<PlayerServiceClient> =>
    playerService ||
    ((playerService = new (await import('./player.client')).PlayerServiceClient()),
    playerService);

let teamService: TeamServiceClient;
export const getTeamService = (): TeamServiceClient =>
    teamService ||
    ((teamService = new (await import('./team.client')).TeamServiceClient()),
  teamService);

let refereeService: RefereeServiceClient;
export const getRefereeService = (): RefereeServiceClient =>
    refereeService ||
  ((refereeService = new (await import('./referee.client')).RefereeServiceClient()),
  refereeService);

let friendService: FriendServiceClient;
export const getFriendService = (): FriendServiceClient =>
    friendService ||
  ((friendService = new (await import('./friend.client')).FriendServiceClient()),
  friendService);

let prizeService: PrizeServiceClient;
export const getPrizeService = (): PrizeServiceClient =>
    prizeService ||
  ((prizeService = new (await import('./prize.client')).PrizeServiceClient()),
  prizeService);

let winnerService: WinnerServiceClient;
export const getWinnerService = (): WinnerServiceClient =>
    winnerService ||
  ((winnerService = new (await import('./winner.client')).WinnerServiceClient()),
  winnerService);

let calendarService: CalendarServiceClient;
export const getCalendarService = (): CalendarServiceClient =>
    calendarService ||
  ((calendarService = new (await import('./calendar.client')).CalendarServiceClient()),
  calendarService);

// and so on... a lot more...
```

As you can see there are **many** service clients.

I'm using this code because I thought it was better given my web app structure based on routes almost overlapping with client services:

I mean, if the player goes from `/home` to `/players` page I can use it like this:

- components/players.svelte

```
import { getPlayerService } from "main";

const playerService = await getPlayerService();
const players = await playerService.queryPlayers();
```

In this way, if the `PlayerService` does not exist, it is imported at the moment and returned, otherwise it returns the one imported and instantiated before.

Since the user switches pages frequently this way I can avoid the sudden creation and destruction of those clients, right?

But in this way I am using **global variables** which I don't like to use and I'm using **verbose, DRY and long code** in each component.

Is there a way to use the below code in components instead?

```
import { playerService } from "main";

const players = await playerService.queryPlayers();
```

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Thank you. I updated. Can you help me?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular**
If you use Angular you are able to use store. For example [ngxs](https://www.ngxs.io/) or [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/docs) modules for your application.

One more way in angular use [resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

> Interface that classes can implement to be a data provider. A data
> provider class can be used with the router to resolve data during
> navigation. The interface defines a resolve() method that is invoked
> when the navigation starts. The router waits for the data to be
> resolved before the route is finally activated.

//player.resolver.ts

```
class PlayerResolver implements Resolve<number> {
   private req = false;
   private repSubject = new ReplaySubject(null);

   constructor(private service: PlayerServiceClient) { }

   public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable {
        if (!this.req) {
            this.req = true;

            this.service.get().subscribe(res => this.repSubject.next(res));
        }
        return this.subject.pipe(first());
    }
}
```

//app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
...
    {
     path: 'player'
     resolve: {data: PlayerResolver}
    },
    {
     path: 'friend'
     resolve: {data: FriendResolver}
    }
]
```

**ReactiveX**

If you use RxJs in your app, you would to do caching, create BaseSender:
//base.sender.ts

```
let hash = require('object-hash');

class BaseSender {

  ...
  protected httpSenderWithCache(service: Observable<any>,param): Observable<any> {
    const id = hash(param);

    if (!this.cache$[id]) {
      this.expireCache(id, time);
      this.cache$[id] = service.pipe(
        shareReplay(1), // last value
        catchError((err) => console.log(err))
      );
    }

    return this.cache$[id];
  }

}
```

shareReplay(1) gets last result.  const id = hash(param); generate unique hash for caching.

//player.service.ts

```
export class PlayerService extends BaseSender {
   ....
   public get(param = null): Observable<any> {
    param = param || {};

    const data = {
        url: 'https://example.com/player',
        options: {
          params: param,
        },
      };
    const request$ = this.http.get(data.url, data.options);

    return this.httpSenderWithCache(request$, data);
  }
}
```

**General**

If you don't use it all.

1. Install and configire [inversify-binding-decorators](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-binding-decorators/) with decorators for DI in app. In main.ts create container.

//main.ts

```
    import { injectable, Container } from "inversify";
    import { provide, buildProviderModule } from "inversify-binding-decorators"; 
    import "reflect-metadata";

    var container = new Container();
    // Reflects all decorators provided by this package and packages them into 
    // a module to be loaded by the container
    container.load(buildProviderModule());
```

2. Create interface `ClientServiceInterface`

//client-service.interface.ts

```
interface ClientServiceInterface {
  public get(param = null);
}
```

3. Create services

```
    @provide(PlayerServiceClient)
    export class PlayerServiceClient implements ClientServiceInterface {
    
      private result;
    
      public function get() {
         if(!result) {
           return fetch('https://ex.com/player')
                   .then(res => {
                      this.result = res;
                      return Promise.resolve(res) 
                    })
         }
         return Promise.resolve(result);  
      }
    }
```

4. in your components you have to inject service

```
  class PlayerComponent {
       constructor(private playerService: PlayerServiceClient) {
         playerService.get().then(...)
       }
    }
```

**Update**

**Singletone**

you are able to wrap service or create Singleton;

```
import {PlayerServiceClient} from '../compoments/player.client';

export class PlayerServiceSingleton {
  private static instance: PlayerServiceClient;
  private constructor() {}

  public static getInstance(): PlayerServiceClient {
    if (!PlayerServiceSingleton.instance) {
      PlayerService.instance = new PlayerServiceClient();
    }

    return PlayerServiceSingleton.instance;
  }

}


export const playerService = PlayerServiceSingleton.getInstance();
```

use

```
import {playerService} from './singletone/player.st';
const players = playerService.queryPlayers();
```

**Factory**.

More beautiful code. It will not reduce code however create more readable. You can create factory:
Create config services for factory:

//factory/services.list.ts

```
export default {
  player: {
    imp: async () => await import('../compoments/player.client'),
    className: 'PlayerServiceClient',
    instance: null,
  },
  friend: {
    imp: async () => await import('../compoments/friend.client'),
    className: 'FriendServiceClient',
    instance: null,
  }
};
```

Create factory:

//factory/service.factory.ts

```
import SERVICES from './services.list';

export class ServiceFactory {
   public static services = SERVICES;

   public static async run(name): Promise<any> {
      if (!ServiceFactory.services[name].instance) {
        ServiceFactory.services[name].instance =
          new (await ServiceFactory.services[name].imp())[ServiceFactory.services[name].className]();
      }

     return ServiceFactory.services[name].instance;
   }
}
```

Call in your component

```
const playerService = await ServiceFactory.run('player');
```

**Update**

**Decorator**.

Added decorator for calling hook `init` in your component.

//loader.decorastor.ts

```
export function loader(param: {waitForReady: Promise<any>, params: any[]}) {
  return (target: any) => {
    const fun: any = async () => {
      const obj = new target(...param.params);
      const init = await param.waitForReady;
      obj.init(init);
      return  true;
    };

    return fun();
  };
}
```

In your component

```
import {ServiceFactory} from 'factory/service.factory';

@loader({
  waitForReady: ServiceFactory.run('friend'),
  params: []
})
 class FriendComponent {


  // 'init' is hook how will have being calls after resolve promise waitForReady
  public init(service) {
    console.log(service.queryFriends());
  }
 }
```

If you need add object in constructor you should add params array for example

```
//fake objects for the component. it will able some services, models
class A {}
const a = new A();   
class B {}
const b = new B();


@loader({
  waitForReady: ServiceFactory.run('friend'),
  params: [a, b]
})
 class PlayerComponent {

  constructor(private a: A, private b: B) {}

  public init(data) {
    console.log(data.queryPlayers());
  }
 }
```

**Update**

what your project might look like WITHOUT any Frameworks [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vfwu6t-ksj3k4)(here Angular need only start main.ts and index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for this complex answer. I find it quite complicated, is there anything simpler?

Comment: @FredHors hi. Added Singleton wrapper to answer. In this case PlayerServiceClient constructor will call only one time

Comment: Added factory for example how create more  readable code.

Comment: And added Decorator Loader for hook init. You can rewrite code with Components and components will create in decorator. Init hook will calling after loading playerService or FriendService or other.  I think it helps you